# MS Edge sending one field in ajax request with bad characters â€Ž. How to omit?

Tags: ajax, tomcat, jquery-plugins, character-encoding, microsoft-edge

I'm using a time and date controller plugin for jQuery: http://jonthornton.github.com/jquery-timepicker/

In a form on a web page, the default values from a date and a time picker are combined to make a date time string and sent with an Ajax request to a servlet sitting on a Tomcat 8 server running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

In Chrome, this works as expected - all JSON text is received as intended.

With MS Edge (IE does not have this problem), the characters come back with garbage characters: â€Ž preceding every character. This appears to be the upside down quote character according to an online reference.

Example:

```
"timeReported":"â€Ž6â€Ž/â€Ž22â€Ž/â€Ž2017 â€Ž10â€Ž:â€Ž29â€Ž:â€Ž09â€Ž â€ŽAM","description":"whatthewhat"
```

All other fields in the JSON submitted are just fine, the description above being an example.

I populate the fields on the form with this bit of Javascript:

```
$('#TimeReported .time').timepicker({
            'showDuration': true,
            'timeFormat': 'g:ia',                      
            'step': 5
        });

$('#TimeReported .date').datepicker({
            'format': 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            'autoclose': true
        });
```

And read the values from the inputs like this:

```
// joined to avoid any problems with unary + which may take some values as numbers
var timeelements= [
    String($('#TimeReported .date').val()), 
    String($('#TimeReported .time').val())
];
var issueTimeReported=timeelements.join(' ');
```

The value that is derived and placed into the json record debugs from IE as:

```
"‎6‎/‎22‎/‎2017 ‎1‎:‎00‎:‎51‎ ‎PM"
```

The data is submitted as JSON via jQuery with the following options:

```
type : "POST",
url : "submitForm.page",
async: true,
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json;charset=Windows-1252',
processData: false,
data : JSON.stringify(rdata),
```

Reading a bit, I find that this is commonly a misalignment of encodings, where utf-8 or ISO-whatever conflicts with Windows-1252.

I also noticed the debug console in Edge reporting the HTTP header and the page were sending conflicting encodings, so I removed all page specific encodings and applied a filter on the web.xml on tomcat to force everything to Windows-1252.

```
 <!-- A filter that sets character encoding that is used to decode -->
  <!-- parameters in a POST request -->

    <filter>
        <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>Windows-1252</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>

   <!-- The mapping for the Set Character Encoding Filter -->
   <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
```

This seems to have resolved the conflicting encoding warning, but the results received at the server are still the same.  The effective doctype is X-UA-Compatible (via meta tag).

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

I would like to prevent these characters from being sent from the browser, but if necessary, I could explicitly filter them in the servlet. It seems that the problem is between IE's backend, submitting the Ajax request, and Tomcat, and I don't think it's on Tomcat's end.

I've worked around this problem by catching the date parsing exception my code throws when trying to ingest this data and providing a suitable substitute (it only does it with the default values from the controls, which is "now", so we substitute "now" server side when this blows.)

*But* that's not the answer. The fact that selecting values from the controls bypasses the issue, e.g. not default values, suggests that there may be a problem with the jQuery time and date picker plugin I'm using.

We've submitted an issue on the plugin.  At this time all testing points to the the way the controls are initialized. https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker/issues/624

Comment: FYI Microsoft Edge is not a version of Internet Explorer; it's a completely different browser w/ a different codebase.

Comment: Thanks - I was under the impression it still used the same core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem typically arises in web development due to a mismatch between character sets on the ajax request and receiver system.  Everything tried in the question would normally resolve this issue, namely ensuring whichever character set is set as expected in the SetCharacterEncodingFilter matches that provided in the incoming web request contentType.

In this specific instance, the issue lies within a third party plugin, so there is no specific resolution to this particular question, though the root problem is addressable and correctable.

Comment: Marked as answered so it is not floating in the unanswered question queue.